# Can i put 2 values in 1 textbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to put 2 values in 1 text box using javascript?
another question just dont answer if dont antw to, may i know how to if-else numbers like (enter-age 18-60 only)

```
<script>
function greeting() {
var name; 
var name = name.value;
document.getElementById("greeting1").value = name;
var greet;
var timep = time.value;
if (timep == "M") {
    greet = "Good Morning";
    document.getElementById("greeting1").value = greet;
    }
    else if (timep == "E") {
    greet = "Good Evening";
    document.getElementById("greeting1").value = greet;
    }
    else{
    alert("Not Allowed")
    }
    }       
</script>
<body>
<p>Enter Name::</p> <input type="text" id="name"  />
<p>Enter Time Period [M/E]::</p> <input type="text" id="time"  />
<button onclick="greeting()">TRY</button>
<input type="text" id="greeting1" readonly  />
```

Comment: why not just make 2 textboxs

Comment: The field can only have _one_ value; but noone is stopping you from _concatenation_ multiple texts into one value that you then assign in one go, or from _appending_ to the already existing value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append multiple values to same text field use `.value += greet`

```js
function greeting() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var greet;
  var timep = time.value;

  if (timep == "M") {
    greet = "Good Morning";
  } else if (timep == "E") {
    greet = "Good Evening";
  } else {
    alert("Not Allowed")
  }
  
  document.getElementById("greeting1").value = greet + ' ' + name;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter Name::</p> <input type="text" id="name" />
<p>Enter Time Period [M/E]::</p> <input type="text" id="time" />
<button onclick="greeting()">TRY</button>
<input type="text" id="greeting1" readonly />
```

---

Solution without entering time:

```js
function greeting() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var hour = new Date().getHours();
  var greeter = document.getElementById("greeting1");
  
  greeter.value = name;

  if (hour < 12) {
    greeter.value += " Good Morning";
  } else {
    greeter.value += " Good Evening";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Enter Name::</p> <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"/>
<button onclick="greeting()">TRY</button>
<input type="text" id="greeting1" readonly />
```

Comment: How about greeting first before name? when i try to run nameis the first one to appear before the greeting

Comment: @lilrookie Check updated answer

Comment: Use `let` or `const` instead of `var`, it's a bad habit to use global variable everywhere